# Global Array property definition

Tags: delphi

I would like to define a property which is a dynamic global array.

```
private
class var FArray;
public
class property myArray : array of byte read FArray write FArray;
```

I have globalvalues unit. My program open an image and get the zoom layer and resolutions. For example: if my image has 5 zoom layer, my property array' s length will be 5. I declare this property only one time until the close and change image. I want to access this property from every unit, so it must be global and dynamic array. Also property too. How can i declare this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

```
type
  TMyGlobalClass = class
  private
    class var FArray: TArray<Byte>;
  public
    class property myArray: TArray<Byte> read FArray write FArray;
  end;
```

One wonders whether or not it's worth making this a property. A property gives the appearance of encapsulation, but in this case you've got nothing more than a global variable with mild obfuscation. Since you are giving complete access to both read and write, you are perhaps as well writing it like this:

```
type
  TMyGlobalClass = class
  public
    class var myArray: TArray<Byte>;
  end;
```

This is nothing more than a global array contained in the scope of `TMyGlobalClass`.

And just to try to cover all bases, it would be remiss of me were I not to mention the commonly held view that global state is often a sign of poor design. Surely you can encapsulate in some manner.

Comment: Thank you for response, i got it. Honestly, i don't know use property in where exactly. But i am learning thanks to you :)

Comment: last question david, how can i set this length?

Comment: When it's a property, you have to do this: `var LArray: TArray<Byte>... SetLength(LArray, N); TMyGlobalClass.myArray := LArray;` and I think this means that the second option in my answer is more convenient. Because you can just do `SetLength(TMyGlobalClass.myArray, N)`. Are you really sure that it is wise to use global data though.

Comment: yes, i understood. I have to access this array from any unit. Now i am clear, thank you very much :)